# Where can I publish poems I translated to Pali?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, resources, language

I have been studying Sanskrit for 6 years, and have published short stories in magazines. I recently became interested in [Pali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali) and translated some classical English poems to Pali.

But unlike Sanskrit though, there is barely any such Pali literature. It is focused more on Buddhism and its teachings.

Where can I publish my Pali translations if I wish to? If not a journal, are there any forums where I can share them? Or some newsletters?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I assume you're looking for journals or forums specifically dedicated to Pali-language literature?

Comment: @F1Krazy Yes, I am looking for something along those lines.

Comment: Since you are doing translations, make sure that what you are translating does not still have a copyright. If you pulled the poems from a book, check copyright info for that book or from that publisher. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @F1Krazy. I realized just after I submitted it that it should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

- The **Pāli Text Society** is a society founded in 1881 to promote the study and publishing of Pāli texts. They maintain the *Journal of the Pali Text Society*. ([Website](http://www.palitext.com/)) ([Archives](http://www.ames.cam.ac.uk/faclib/archive/pts.html))
- **Shambhala Publications** is a small, independent publishing company based in Boulder, Colorado that publishes Buddhist works, including some Pāli cultural works. ([Website](https://www.shambhala.com/))
- The **Dhamma Wheel** forum, which contains subforums for learning and studying the Pāli language. ([Main Website](https://www.dhammawheel.com/)) ([Resources Thread](https://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=950))

You could also explore self-publishing options, i.e. through Amazon Books or the Google Play Store, if you wanted to release a self-curated and edited collection of your Pāli poems for the public to read.

- **Amazon:** [Self Publishing Info Link,](https://www.amazon.com/gp/seller-account/mm-summary-page.html?ld=AZFooterSelfPublish&topic=200260520&ref_=footer_publishing) [Kindle Publishing Link](https://kdp.amazon.com/).
- **Google Play Store:** [How to sell a book on the Google Play store.](https://support.google.com/books/partner/checklist/4489282?hl=en)